# mesh gaussian after rotation matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, rotation, mesh, gaussian

I am trying to rotate the derivative of a gaussian (or the original guassian for that matter) by applying a rotation matrix to the X,Y coordinates and then plotting it as a mesh in matlab, but I'm running into an issue that the plot will only rotate by 90 degress each time and for all n*pi points there is no mesh appearing at all. I am wondering what I am doing wrong, hopefully someone can spot my error. I'm fairly new to matlab so forgive me if the code is not pretty. Thank you!

This is the code that I have:

```
sigma = 4;
[x,y] = deal(-3*sigma:.5:3*sigma);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
B = [transpose(x) transpose(y)];

for i=1:1:16
figure(i);
theta = i*pi/8;
rotation = [cos(theta) sin(theta); -sin(theta) cos(theta)];
A = B * rotation;
[x_new, y_new] = meshgrid(A(:,1)', A(:,2)');
mesh(x_new, y_new, dgauss_x(x_new, y_new, sigma));
end

function f = dgauss_x(x, y, sigma)
%first order derivative of Gaussian
f = -x .* gaussian(x, y, sigma) ./ sigma^2;

function f = gaussian(x, y, sigma)
f = exp(-(x .^ 2 + y .^ 2)/(2*sigma^2)) / (sqrt(2*pi*(sigma^2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. It was a dumb error. Basically I had to create a meshgrid for X and Y, reshape it into an Nx2 matrix of X and Y. Apply the rotation matrix, then reshape back and apply the Gaussian. 
The code looks as follows (could be cleaned up):

```
for i=1:1:16
figure(i);
theta = i*pi/8;
rotation = [cos(theta) -sin(theta); sin(theta) cos(theta)];
X1 = reshape(X, length(x)*length(x), 1);
Y1 = reshape(Y, length(y)*length(y), 1);
B2 = [X1 Y1];
A = B2 * rotation;
X1 = A(:,1);
X1 = reshape(X1, length(x), length(x));
Y1 = A(:,2);
Y1 = reshape(Y1, length(y), length(y));
mesh(X1, Y1, dgauss_x(X1, Y1, sigma));
end
```